# Comparing Two Data frame Columns to Add a New Column With the Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

using this as a demo data set:

```
    a = [['11', '2'], ['15', '70'], ['8', '5']]
    df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Person','one', 'two'])

    Out[8]: 
        Person one  two
    0   Jim    10  1.2
    1   John   15  70
    2   Bob    8   5
```

I want to create some sort of logic calculation to compare only columns' **one** and **two**,
comparing both of them and outputting a new column with the results

a calculation like this if column **one** is > column **two** put a 1 else 0

Desired output:

```
    Out[8]: 
        Person one  two  Results
    0   Jim    10  1.2   1
    1   John   15  70    0
    2   Bob    8   5     1
```

Comment: Your pseudo approach is correct: `df['Results'] = (df['one'] > df['two']).astype(int)`

Comment: As an aside your code constructor and shown sample code appear to be totally unrelated. Also your "number" values appear to be strings making `>` lexicographic sorting not numeric sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['Results'] = df['one'].gt(df['two']).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Results'] = (df['one'] > df['two']).astype(int)
```

**Edit:**

Use:

```
df['Results'] = np.where(df['one'] > df['two'], 'Higher', 'Lower')
```

Comment: What would you have to alter if you would want to instead of 1 or zero be a text value like "higher" or "Lower"?

Comment: @MarcU Check my **Edit:** section